# uno-platform vb.net desktop application targeting MAC OS

Tags: vb.net

I have huge vb.net application (with crystal reports, db connections, complex custom controls etc)
is it possible to run this in Mac Os using uno-platform?

vb.net natively not supports Mac, so asking here if this new platform supports.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the answer is no, unless that platform also supports ActiveX.
Under the .NET surface, the Crystal Runtime has dependencies on ActiveX.